# rake task scheduling with whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, whenever

Hello I was trying to run a rake task every 5 minutes with this schedule code using the whenever gem

```
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"

every 10.minutes do
  rake "delete:old_offers"
end
```

But the code never execute. If I try to run my task with:

> rake delete:old_offers

everything works great, so the problem is in the schedule file. Please I need your help to solve this issues.

I'm planning to execute this task every 60 days in my heroku app, so I could the schedule has to work also on heroku.

Thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE

Sorry guys, I have to set the environment to development like this

```
set :environment, 'development'
```

Comment: have you run `wheneverize .` at your project's root directory?

Comment: Yes, I ran this command bundle exec wheneverize to create the schedule.rb file and then I ran this command bundle exec whenever

Comment: what's your dev environment? win, linux, mac os?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.8.2, ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 2):

After you write your schedule, you need to actually update your crontab:

```
whenever --update-crontab
```

Simply running the `whenever` command by itself will only show you the schedule in cron format.

Comment: Dylan I did, but nothing happen. What else can I do??? How do I know if the task run, because this set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log" it's never created